# How to sort in room database

Tags: java, android, android-room

**Hey.
How can I sort the list of movies by rating?(voteAverage)**

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
public class Movie {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int uniqueId;
    private int id;
    private String genre;
    private int voteCount;
    private String title;
    private String originalTitle;
    private String overview;
    private String posterPath;
    private String bigPosterPath;
    private String backdropPath;
    private double voteAverage;
    ...
```

**MovieDao**

```
@Dao
public interface MovieDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM movies")
    LiveData<List<Movie>> getAllMovies();

    ...
```

**For some reason, it doesn't sort by @Query("SELECT * FROM movies SORT BY voteAverage")**

Answer (score 5):

Use `ORDER BY`

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY voteAverage")
```

you can use `ASC` or `DESC`  for ascending and descending order

Comment: This should work fine , did you write any filter on top of list ?

Comment: I receive data through the API, there are no filters, I rechecked everything